# How to redirect a sub directory except for the landing page?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect all my WordPress posts under the sub-directory `/plays/` to the home directory (`/`) except for the landing page.

- So if you go to `example.com/plays/hello` you will be redirected to `example.com/hello`
- But if you go to `example.com/plays` or `example.com/plays/` you will stay on that page.

How can I do this? I'm assuming it has to be done through a redirect via `.htaccess` but I don't know how.

Comment: I've improved the formatting of this question as well as removed "please help".    This should help the question get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule should work :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if the request is for "/plays" or "/plays/", skip the rule#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/plays/?$
#otherwise redirect to homepage#
RewriteRule ^plays/(.+)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```